# MYSQL - How to optimize 3 LEFT Joined tables?

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing

**Problem:** My query works perfectly fine when the rows of each tables are just few (say less than a thousand). **But when I tried to populate the db with dummy data, the page loads endlessly.**

I am using 3 tables to join:

1. **students** - it holds basic information of the students (7,000+ rows)

   Indexed columns: **student_id**, **grade** and **sex**
2. **absenteeism** - this holds the records for absences (31,000+ rows)

   Indexed columns: **absent_id**, **student_id**, **excused**
3. **tardiness** - this holds the records for tardiness (19,000+ rows)

   Indexed columns: **tardi_id**, **student_id**, **excused**

The output table looks like this:

```
Name       | Grade | Section | Sex | Age | Tardiness Count | Absence Count 
____________________________________________________________________
John Smith | 7     | E05-A   | Male| 18  | 6               | 5
```

And this is my **query:**

```
SELECT students.student_id , students.name_l, students.name_f, students.name_m, students.grade, students.section, students.age_s, students.sex, 

(SELECT COUNT(distinct absenteeism.absent_id) FROM absenteeism 
 WHERE absenteeism.excused=0 AND absenteeism.student_id = students.student_id ) AS absents, 

(SELECT COUNT(distinct tardiness.tardi_id) FROM tardiness 
 WHERE tardiness.excused=0 AND tardiness.student_id = students.student_id ) AS tardi 

FROM students 
LEFT JOIN absenteeism ON absenteeism.student_id = students.student_id 
LEFT JOIN tardiness ON tardiness.student_id = students.student_id 
GROUP BY students.student_id 
ORDER BY name_l ASC LIMIT 0, 15
```

My query simply fetched all of the data that I need to display from the **students** table then counts all records in **absenteeism** and **tardiness** table that is not marked excused with the corresponding **student_id** for each rows.

And here is the **extended EXPLAIN** of the query:

```
id  select_type         table       type    possible_keys       key         key_len ref                         rows    filtered    extra

1   PRIMARY             students    index   NULL                PRIMARY     34      NULL                        6900    100.00      Using temporary; Using filesort 
1   PRIMARY             absenteeism ref     student_id          student_id  34      lnhs.students.student_id    1583    100.00      Using index 
1   PRIMARY             tardiness   ref     student_id          student_id  34      lnhs.students.student_id    3851    100.00      Using index 
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tardiness   ref     student_id,excused  student_id  34      func                        3851    100.00      Using where 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  absenteeism ref     student_id,excused  student_id  34      func                        1583    100.00      Using where
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is likely killing you are the two correlated aggregation queries appearing in your `SELECT` clause.  Instead, do the aggregations in separate bona-fide subqueries and then join them to your `students` table.

```
SELECT
    s.*,      -- replace with whatever columns you actually want
    COALESCE(t1.num_absent, 0) AS num_absent,
    COALESCE(t2.num_tardy, 0) AS num_tardy
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT absent_id) AS num_absent
    FROM absenteeism
    WHERE excused = 0
    GROUP BY student_id
) t1
    ON s.student_id = t1.student_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT tardi_id) AS num_tardy
    FROM tardiness
    WHERE excused = 0
    GROUP BY student_id
) t2
    ON s.student_id = t2.student_id
ORDER BY
    s.name_l
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Note that I use `COALESCE()` on the absent and late counts for each student.  The reason for this, and the reason why a `LEFT JOIN` was (wisely) used is that it could be the case that a given student be neither absent nor late.  An `INNER JOIN` would have removed that student from the result set.  Instead, `COALESCE` allows to detect that a student did not appear in either the absent or late subqueries, and in these cases we can report zero for the respective figure.

Comment: Thank you! The page now loads instantly! Your solution works like 100x faster than mine. Man, I really should study more in MYSQL. I'm pretty sure this is also going to help me in the future. Thanks